# Crypto++ Version 5.6.0

Tags: c++

anyone used the latest version of cryptopp. i think its 5.6.0. I have a solution working in unix. but in windows I am stuck. Anyone here already using cryptopp 5.6 in vs2008 could you please give very specific instructions on how you compiled this? i have also posted in the cryptopp user groups for an answer. There are some instructions but for vs 6.0 and not the version i am using. So, I am not sure how to proceed.

The errors are as follows:
error: lnk2005  already defined in cryptlib(iterhash.obj) 
                                                     (cryptlib.obj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I did was open the `cryptest.sln` file and tell it to build.

EDIT: Visual Studio did have to convert from VS2005 format but it compiles and runs just fine.

Comment: ok i did that already and it creates an output\debug directory with the cryptlib.lib after that do i just add that to the linker and thats it?

Comment: Oh: Note that you need to ensure you use the debug build of the library with your debug builds and the release version with your release builds. ;)

Comment: i think that might be the issue i have. getting a lot of lnk2005 errors. so i build it with debug (active) my solution also has debug(active) both in win32. i am very new to vs2008 so this is a bit new to me. i did not make a release version yet. been just working with debug version. some of the stuff i am seeing is warning : lnk4044 unrecognized option /lcryptopp; ignored. error: lnk2005 <a bunch of stuff> already defined in cryptlib(iterhash.obj) (cryptlib.obj) etc etc any ideas?

Comment: i just moved the cryptlib.lib into solutions explorer after it was made and thats it. then just did a build all of my solution that is how I am doing it but yet experience the aforementioned errors.

Comment: Make sure you are building the library with the same versions of the C runtime. Crypto++ by default builds with the static runtime, but when you create a project in Visual Studio, you get the DLL runtime by default. To change this, rightclick on the project, hit properties, go to C++ -> Code Generation, and change `Runtime Library` to the non DLL version for your project. Also, it would be helpful to others if you would edit the specific errors you are getting into your question.

Comment: well sir you are awesome. that worked! but only one thing is left. when i start without debugging or with for that matter it says "unable to start program.exe. "The system cannot find the file specified". this is after the program compiled and linked correctly.